# Delete "row" in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

My Firebase looks something like this:

```
dates:
 -KEwpqOQA2S1Jb3wfKVG: "2016-04-10"
 -KEupqdfsdfbQS3wfKDF: "2016-04-11"
 -KEupqdENJSDJSQS3wfS: "2016-04-12"
```

I have a calendar that detects a date on a tap. As I gathered there is function **.queryEqualToValue** so I've input `date` (here is stored tapped date) as a parameter. I can get key and value but I don't really get how to remove that line altogether.

I tried to make this:

```
let find = ref.childByAppendingPath("dates").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(date.toString(DateFormat.Custom("YYYY-MM-dd")))
```

But **.removeValue()** is not popping-out when I type `find.removeValue()` in new line.

It seems I don't get how to delete entire row in Firebase. Can somebody, please, enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can get key

If you have access to the key, then you can simply do

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("dates/\(theKey)").removeValue()
```